# Computing $\iint \limits_R \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y$ where $R=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} : y \geq x, 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 2 \}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

*Homework question, so just hints please*

> Sketch the region
>   $$
> R=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} : y \geq x, 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 2 \}
> $$
>   and, by changing to polar coordinates, compute
>   $$
> \iint \limits_R \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y
> $$

So I have the sketch, as from WolframAlpha:

http://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP23281g329ghb4ef13b1f000019cf3e27f69cigib?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=58&w=200.&h=193.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips

and so, in polar coordinates, the region is described by
$$
R=\{ (r,\theta) \in \mathbb{R} : 1 \leq r \leq 2, \frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{5 \pi}{4} \}
$$

and thus we have the integral
$$
\begin{align*}
\iint \limits_R \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y
&= \int_1^2 \int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{5 \pi}{4} \! \frac{r\cos\theta \, r\sin\theta}{(r\cos\theta)^2 + (r\sin\theta)^2} \mathrm{d}\theta \, \mathrm{d}r\\
&= \int_1^2 \int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{5 \pi}{4} \! \sin\theta \, \cos\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta\, \mathrm{d}r\\
\end{align*}
$$
but then clearly this is wrong as it evaluates to $0$. However, I don't see where I have made a mistake.

Comment: You forgot to multiply by the determinant of the [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) $\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(\theta ,r)}\right| = r$.

Comment: btw the total result *should* be zero by symmetry. If you look at the four parts contained in the regions $(r,\theta)$ with  1) $\theta\in [\pi/4,\pi/2]$, 2) $\theta \in [\pi/2,3\pi/4]$, 3) $\theta \in [3\pi/4,\pi]$ and 4) $\theta \in [\pi,5\pi/4]$ then the integral over 1) + 2) is zero (symmetric about the $x$ axis and $xy/(x^2+y^2)$ is odd in $x$) and 3)+4) is zero (symmetric about the $y$ axis and $xy/(x^2+y^2)$ is odd in $y$).

Comment: it could very well be $0$ however your $dxdy$ converted to $dr d \theta$ not $r dr d \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done seems to be correct except that the area element $dxdy$ becomes $r dr d\theta$ in polar coordinates, and the maximum value of r is $\sqrt{2}$. However, this will still give 0 but what's wrong with that?